# cordova 'admob free' in ios - exception when app running

Tags: ios, cordova, admob

https://ratson.github.io/cordova-plugin-admob-free

running results in exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'GADInvalidInitializationException', reason: 'The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. Google AdMob publishers should follow instructions here: https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-ios-update-plist to include the AppMeasurement framework, set the -ObjC linker flag, and set GADApplicationIdentifier with a valid App ID. Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here: https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-ios-update-plist'
```

I set the 'GADApplicationIdentifier' value in the *.plist file but still get the same error.
What it can be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue and resolved it by adding `GADIsAdManagerApp` key with a boolean value `YES` to my app's `Info.plist`.

[image]

As you can see in the [sdk documents](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/ios/quick-start#update_your_infoplist),

> This step is required as of Google Mobile Ads SDK version 7.42.0.
>   Failure to add add this Info.plist entry results in a crash with the
>   message: "The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly."

Comment: Thanks, GADIsAdManagerApp Working fine now!